# MySQL Data Entities com Mysql Data 5.3.7

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

Gostaria de saber se existe algum meio de usar o `MySQL.Data.Entities` com a versão do `MySQL.Data` 5.3.7.

Nas especificação [aqui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySQL.Data.Entities/6.4.4) fala que funciona com o `MySQL.Data` (≥ 6.4.4.0).

Existe algum outro meio de usar o `Entity Framework (Code First)` com a versão 5.3.7 do `Mysql.Data`?

Answer (score 1):

## Este pacote está depreciado

O substituto natural dele é o [MySql.Data.Entity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/).

[Repare que a última atualização do Entities é janeiro de 2014](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entities/).

Apenas troque o Entities pelo Entity, no singular.

## Usando com MySql.Data versão 5.3.7

Não é possível. O suporte, infelizmente, começa na versão 6.4.4.

Comment: Mas mesmo assim ele só aceita MySql.Data (≥ 6.7.8)

Comment: Por que você quer manter esse pacote?

Comment: Porque o servidor onde está sendo hospedado só suporte Mysql.Data menor que a versão 6

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Atualizei a resposta. Arrume outro servidor. Mais fácil.

Comment: Boa LocaWeb hahahaha. Valeu!

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Sai dessa vida, cara.